# Safari CSS issue vertically misaligning elements with for some `height` value

Tags: html, css, safari

The following code displays fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari (17, Mac+IpadOS) the bar baselines are changing.

Even weirder (and which makes me think it could be a rendering issue), it can be fixed by changing the height component by a few percent point (like 79% instead of 80%, or 58% instead of 60%).

Any idea on a proper fix?

```css
signal {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1.5em;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

signal>i {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #7daa49;
}

signal>i:nth-child(2) {
  height: 60%;
}

signal>i:nth-child(3) {
  height: 80%;
}

signal>i:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<signal class="q4"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></signal>
```

Display on Chrome/Firefox (correct):

[image: correct bars]

Display on Safari (incorrect):

[image: incorrect bars]

Note that on Safari it's not always the same bars who are misaligned, in the screenshot above it's the first two ones, but in the [original issue](https://github.com/lichess-org/lila/issues/14584) it is the ones in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have a problem when for example 40% does not turn out to be a whole number of pixels.

It is therefore going to be difficult to use em for this if you need a fully general solution.

This snippet sets the height to 20px as a demo. 20px gives whole pixel heights. And the result is no misalignment.

```css
signal {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 1.5em;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

signal>i {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #7daa49;
}

signal>i:nth-child(2) {
  height: 60%;
}

signal>i:nth-child(3) {
  height: 80%;
}

signal>i:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<signal class="q4"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></signal>
```

Here is a different approach, making the signal element a grid.

```html
<style>
  signal {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 1px;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1.5em;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  signal>i {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    --h: 40%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #7daa49 0 var(--h), transparent var(--h) 100%);
  }
  
  signal>i:nth-child(2) {
    --h: 60%;
  }
  
  signal>i:nth-child(3) {
    --h: 80%;
  }
  
  signal>i:nth-child(4) {
    --h: 100%;
  }
</style>
<signal class="q4"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></signal>
```

Safari seems happier with that, at least on the version I have (IOS 16) and the height can go back to being based on em.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to rounding calculated sizes to integer pixel values, a problem which is always potentially there but becomes more obvious when your element is only a few pixels in size.

My suggestion would be to use a flexbox to control the layout; it seems to render perfectly.

```css
.q4 {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1.5em;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-items: end;
  gap: 1px;
}

.q4>i {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #7daa49;
}

.q4>i:nth-child(2) {
  height: 60%;
}

.q4>i:nth-child(3) {
  height: 80%;
}

.q4>i:nth-child(4) {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="q4"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
```